# How to Restrict RDP Access in an Azure PaaS Cloud Service

Tags: acl, rdp, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to implement ACL rules in my .cscfg file to restrict access to my cloud service's RDP endpoints (allow only traffic coming from my VNet's Subnet).

I followed this article by Kevin Williamson [How to restrict RDP Access in an azure pass cloud service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2014/12/16/how-to-restrict-rdp-access-in-an-azure-paas-cloud-service.aspx), but there's a problem with the config according to Visual Studio 2013 (it displays the yellow triangle on the "Roles" folder).

I'm using the Azure SDK 2.6.

I enabled the RDP Extension in Visual Studio 2013 itself, and then proceeded to add the necessary markup in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg, but the moment I add the AccessControl and EndpointAcls Visual Studio alerts me to a problem.

I have:

```
<!-- I added this in the NetworkConfiguration opening tag, but before the VirtualNetworkSite and AddressAssignments -->
<AccessControls>
    <AccessControl name="RdpRestrictions">
        <Rule order="100" action="permit" remoteSubnet="10.1.0.0/24"     description="PermitRdp" />
        <Rule order="200" action="deny" remoteSubnet="0.0.0.0/0" description="DenyRdp" />
    </AccessControl>
</AccessControls>
<EndpointAcls>
    <EndpointAcl role="MyEndpoint" endpoint="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.RdpInput" accessControl="RdpRestrictions"/>
</EndpointAcls>
```

I checked and my cscfg file seems valid according to the NetworkConfiguration Schema Defintiion.

I checked that the role described in EndpointAcl does refer to the WebRole for which the Remote Forwarder Plugins have been imported.

What could possibly be wrong? I can't find any information on the internet as to how one could troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Why don't you just re-create the package *without* RDP support and re-deploy? You would then have to manually configure RDP through the Management Console / Powershell if you later need access.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [Network Configuration Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156091.aspx) seems to be outdated in two regards.

1. The EndpointAcl's endpoint attribute is supposed to be "endPoint".
2. The AccessControls end EndpointAcls tags had to be placed at the end of the NetworkConfiguration section (after all the other elements).

Comment: +1 for 'endpoint' -> 'endPoint'. Docs say 'endpoint' where 'endPoint' is required. Getting it wrong leads to a useless generic message. (I spent some time figuring this out on my own.)